# How to change a python code into an application to run in any folder that it is saved with the files that are in the same folder

Tags: python

Good Morning,
I have made a little python code to merge some excel files in an specific windows folder. How can I changing my python code to share with my coleagues in a way that they can run the script in any folder that they want and consequently do the changes in any folder that the script is save, I mean, they have to save the script file .exe in a folder to run with the files that are there. Could you help me? My code is working as I expected, but for save as .exe I need to take off the address folder that I put on the code and change for a place that will work in any place that my colleagues decide to save the file and I don't know how to do that.
Could you help me please.

```
appended_rods = []

for relatorio in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\henrique.fontenelle.N2018001432\Desktop\Rods 19052021'):

    rod_merged = pd.read_excel(relatorio, header = [0])
    extract_state = str(rod_merged.iloc[[],[0]])
    start = extract_state.find("/") + len("/")
    end = extract_state.find(" e suas")
    state = extract_state[start:end]

    extract_period = str(rod_merged.iloc[[],[0]])
    start = extract_period.find("De: ") + len("De: ")
    end = extract_period.find("21.")
    period = extract_period[start:end]+"21"

    rod = pd.read_excel(relatorio, header =[1])
    rod["Regional"] = state
    rod["Período"] = period
   
    appended_rods.append(rod)
reformatedDataSheet = pd.concat(appended_rods, ignore_index=True)
relatorio = reformatedDataSheet.filter(items=['Origem / ROD', 'Categoria / ROD','Item / ROD','Quantidade','Unidade', 'Regional', 'Período'])

relatorio.to_excel(r'C:\Users\henrique.fontenelle.N2018001432\Desktop\Rods 19052021\gravacaoRodConsolidado.xlsx', index = False)
```

Comment: you can use `auto-py-to-exe` to convert your code to exe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Path of `__file__` to change your current working directory to wherever the file you're running is housed.

Let's say your file is `/home/madronos/Documents/some_dir/some_program.py`

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

os.chdir(Path(__file__).parent)
```

Your cwd would now be `/home/madronos/Documents/some_dir`, and your running `.py` would look for files locally within the `some_dir`.

In terms of making a `.exe`, look into `auto-py-to-exe`

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to convert python program to .exe but i would suggest you to use `auto-py-to-exe`.